# C++ Allocation of array of struct

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, allocation

I have to allocate in C++ an array of struct, any struct contains two vector of int. This is my struct:

```
typedef struct _Sample{
vector<int> contourX;
vector<int> contourY;
}Sample;
```

To allocate this array I write the following code:

```
data = (struct _Sample*) malloc(sizeof(struct _Sample) * nsamples);
```

When I try to assign a Sample element to data[0] I have an error a runtime. Where is the problem?

Comment: The vector elements are still of size **0**. How are you accessing them ?

Comment: Sample * data = (Sample*) malloc(sizeof(Sample) * nsamples);// you are using typedef, so use "Sample"

Comment: Why the archaic `typedef struct` in C++?

Comment: purpose of typedef is so you don't have to do what he did "struct _sample"... just simplicity

Comment: @jdl, perhaps in C; in C++, after `struct Sample { /* ... */ };`, `Sample` is full type name; no `struct` required...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to create an array, for that, you should use `new[]` to allocate the memory (and `delete []` to deallocate it).

That way your code should be:

```
Sample* data = new Sample[nsamples];
```

Then you can iterate over each element of your array like any array:

```
for(int i = 0; i < nsamples; i++)
{
    data[i].contourY // do something
    data[i].contourX // do something
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Rule of thumb: Never use `malloc` in C++.<sup>1</sup>  It's a C function, and as such, doesn't do all the C++ stuff like calling constructors.

If you must dynamically allocate memory, use `new` instead.

---

<sup>1. This is a rule with a few exceptions, but for most cases is safe to treat as a blanket rule.</sup>

Comment: Oli, how about extending an allocated memory region? Or hooking up `mmap` to `new` and `new []` operators?

Comment: @VladLazarenko: "rule of thumb" != "blanket rule".

Comment: /me puts himself into "hold" state :) -1 is not me though. Generally, a good rule of thumb for newbies.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `new` - the constructors for your vectors need to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

if you are programming in c++ you could use "new"...like:
    _Sample* data = new _Sample[size];